# Web Scraping filtering result

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm new to vba and i am getting price which site is [store.steampowered.com](http://store.steampowered.com). I am getting prices well but i want to filter results. If result is lower than 2, dont write the result.
i am using this code:

```
y = 1

For x = 1 To 21

    objIE.navigate "http://example.com/market/search?appid=578080#p" & x & "x_name_asc"

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    MsgBox "Checking"

    For Each itemEle In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("market_listing_row_link")

        Prc1 = itemEle.getElementsByClassName("market_listing_right_cell market_listing_their_price")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")(1).textContent

        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & y).Value = Prc1

        y = y + 1

    Next

Next x
```

i tried this code and its not working:

```
If Prc1 > 2 Then

    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & y).Value = Prc1

    y = y + 1

End If
```

For example in excel:

```
D1 : $20.55 USD
D2 : $6.37 USD
D3 : $1.26 USD '-------> i am tring to dont get this
```

Comment: Just as a hint: your link to `store.steampowered.com` actually points to `steam.powered.com`, which is an non-existent domain.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. Interim as one of the types returned is not a string.

This

```
CDbl(Split(Split(Prc1, "$")(1), " ")(0)) > 2
```

ensure you have extracted the numerical part from the return values for comparison against the value 2.

```
Option Explicit

Sub testing()

    Dim x As Long, y As Long, Prc1 As String
    Dim objIE As Object
    Dim itemEle As IHTMLElement

    Set objIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    y = 1

    For x = 1 To 21

        objIE.navigate "http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=578080#p" & x & "x_name_asc"

        Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        For Each itemEle In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("market_listing_row_link")

            On Error Resume Next

            Prc1 = itemEle.getElementsByClassName("market_listing_right_cell market_listing_their_price")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")(1).textContent

            If CDbl(Split(Split(Prc1, "$")(1), " ")(0)) > 2 Then

                Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & y).Value = Prc1
                y = y + 1
            End If

            On Error GoTo 0

        Next

    Next x

    objIE.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: **its getting error:**
Rum-Time error '13': Type mismatch


**Debug is :**
`Set Prc1 = itemEle.getElementsByClassName("market_listing_right_cell market_listing_their_price")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")(1).textContent`

Comment: **d1:** $20.55 USD
**d2:** $6.37 USD
**d3:** $1.26 USD ------> its lower than 2

Comment: I don't get that result with my script above. I get $4.64 USD
 as lowest.

Comment: I'm wondering if the values are changing dynamically and I am missing an error

Comment: Why is it different ? and its repeats same things at 1 to 10 cells.

Comment: its changing dynamically

Comment: i think the repeating may be to do with refresh time?

Comment: what i should do i dont know. am using your macro but its getting similar result with my macro. can ask another question ? i am getting results which is $ x USD . Can i delete USD text with code ?

Comment: Split(Prc1, Chr(32))(0)

Comment: it seems that the new page is not being picked up in the loop.

Comment: Maybe @TimWilliams will come to the rescue

Comment: who he or she is i dont know but i hope :(

Comment: I will have another crack at it but for now it is din dins.